# Find Ocean Depth at a Particular Point in the World (using Google Earth)

Tags: google-earth

Is it possible to find out the depth of the ocean at a particular point in the world?

I’ve been trying to do this with Google Earth, but have not been able to determine this.
The place I would like this for is located at:

(lat) 33°52'13.67”S, (lngt) 151°15'43.91”E

If anyone could  help, it would be much appreciated.

Or, if there are any other applications/data-sets to determine this, that would also be good.

Comment: 18489 feet is what I get on google earth

Comment: It would make it a real answer if you could share with us the way you did that. Answering the way you do a 3 years old question does not help other people. Please have a look on [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps provides an [elevation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple) API endpoint. It will return a negative value for coordinates corresponding to points on the ocean

Comment: This worked! Thanks. ```results": [
{
"elevation": -34.82612609863281,
"location": {
"lat": 58.9923737,
"lng": 18.8588395
},
"resolution": 610.8129272460938
}
]```

Answer (score 1):

http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/viewers/bathymetry/

select More...   NOAA Raster Nautical charts

depths in meters

Answer (score 1):

I would like to note that the depths in the Raster Nautical Charts [posted by user54863](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53044) appear to be in fathoms.

When you hover your mouse over a location on the map, then the elevation is given in meters in the bottom left. This elevation in meters is about double the depths shown on the charts, suggesting the latter are in fathoms.

Answer (score 0):

This site allows you to enter coordinates and it gives you altitude: https://www.geoplaner.com/
Negative numbers are given for ocean locations, which means depth.